# Robot Framework: Continue FOR loop if any keyword fails inside the loop

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework, ui-automation

In the robot framework, I want to continue For Loop even if any keyword fails inside the Loop. For example, I have the code as shown below:

```
FOR    ${member}    IN    @{all data members}
      Keyword 1   ${member}
      Keyword 2   ${member}
      ..............
      Keyword n   ${member}
END
```

If any keyword (e.g. Keyword 2) fails, the FOR loop execution should continue.

Answer (score 3):

You could use keyword `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure` before each keyword or use keyword `Run Keyword And Return Status` and manually handle errors.

Comment: It seems that we do not have try...catch like thing that could be used inside the for loop in robot framework. Can we customize the keyword "Run Keyword And Continue On Failure" as "Run Keyword And Continue On Failure With Failure Status" so that it can also return status(true, false) along with showing failure exceptions.

Comment: You could try to use keyword `Run Keyword And Ignore Error`. It returns strings `PASS` or `FAIL` and return value or error that happened https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems it can solve my problem to some extent.